# Using $_GET to put an image behind SSL from external site

Tags: php, image, proxy, get

I want to create a basic image proxy for my forum so I can get rid of mixed content warnings. The below code allows you to go to "https://www.example.com/proxy.php?url=http://www.example.net/image.jpg" and it loads the image via https. Is there a safer way I can do this and how can I make it so only the server can use this and not other sites?

```
$image = htmlentities($_GET['url']);
header('Content-Type: image/png');
if(isset($image)){echo file_get_contents($image);}
```

Comment: you can use direct <img src="<?php echo $image;?>"> full url will show you image

Comment: I am going to use the proxy.php file in bbcode so $image will change very often. It will be echo'ed out somewhere else